# ¿Cómo consumir JSON api con Ruby on Rails?

Tags: json, api, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

me estoy iniciando en rails, y esto es sobre todo una pregunta de concepto, de como consumir un **API-json**.

Por lo que entiendo, cuando creas un modelo **active record**, este hace que los datos se guarden en la base de datos, y aquí va mi duda.

Partiendo de un api hecha en nodejs que se encarga de que los registros se guarden en la base de datos, para generar las vistas y tratar los datos que esta **api** me arroje, en ruby on rails:

Bastaría con crear un **modelo ruby** a pelo que **no** herede de **active record**, y con la gema *rest-client* hacer las llamadas a node?

Luego para crear los **controllers**, cambiría algo de la manera de crearlos en relación a si el modelo hereda o no de active record?

Así evitaría que *RoR* guarde en la base de datos?

Esto sería un uso correcto o estoy totalmente equivocado en el planteamiento de la aplicación?

Comment: Lo que mencionas es posible en rails. Crear una vista controlador y una capa de pseudo modelo (que más creo sería una capa de servicio) que haga los requests a tu server node. No es necesaria la existencia de un modelo para crear un controlador en rails. Respecto a si sería un uso correcto supongo es debatible, claramente tu implementación no se acercaría ni de lejos a la funcionalidad de active record y siempre estarías limitado por el acceso que te entrega la API node, sin contar un peor rendimiento vs acceder directamente a la BD.

Comment: @AlterLagos entonces, si no entiendo mal y dejando de lado el active record, y que es un diseño ineficiente por rendimiento y acceso al api, no tendría que crear un modelo para poder consumir el json que me ofrece, como se harían los scopes con queries que de normal se situan en el modelo?

Comment: Si la API funciona con graphql, podrías hacer una especie de query, pero si no, estás restringido a las limitaciones de la información que te entrega la API. Ahora, como implementar eso, es una pregunta amplia que no cabe mucho dentro del ámbito de S.O., pero personalmente probaría una capa de servicios que tuviese los scopes que mencionas y conectar con la api,luego los "modelos" serían simples PORO con su correspondiente mapeo de atributos,o más simple aún, mapeando los registros desde un json a un objeto  `OpenStruct`. Pero, insisto, como implementarlo, queda a criterio de cada programador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe una gema para Rails que puede ayudarte con tu problema:

https://github.com/rails/activeresource

Así no tienes que crearte tu propio "modelo". Ésta imita el funcionamiento de ActiveRecord y tendrás una interfaz similar. Pero está enfocado para API REST y no es lo mismo que una base de datos por lo tanto no puedes hacer queries como harías con un MySQL por ejemplo.

Respecto a las preguntas dependerá de cuál sea el problema a resolver.
Si no necesitas guardar datos en tu base de datos, entonces haces bien en usar los datos en caliente para ejecutar la lógica de negocio necesaria. Ten en cuenta los tiempos de respuestas de la API.

En cuanto a los controladores, puedes crearlos a mano o generarlos. Entiendo que tu duda viene a la hora de usar el generardor de Rails. Debido a que Rails es un framework basado en convenciones, si generas un controlador con un nombre determinado en plural este buscará un modelo en singular con el mismo nombre. Si usas la gema que te he pasado como comparte interfaz con ActiveRecord puede que el controlador generado practicamente funcione con tu clase de ActiveResource (debes ponerle el mismo nombre del controlador en singular) y apenas tengas que hacer cambios.

Si este es un buen uso o no, depende del problema a resolver, contexto, requisitos, etc. Si solo quieres usar Rails para hacer peticiones a una API y mostrar una vista, quizás sería mas adecuado usar ReactJS, VueJS o AngularJS.